# PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "posts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_ac52d45g3n"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-resource

Собираю данные формы:

```
data = new FormData()
data.append('post[title]', _this.post.title)
data.append('post[category_id]', _this.post.category_id)
data.append('post[content]', _this.post.content)
```

И отправляю:

```
this.$http.patch('/posts/' + this.id, data)
```

В форме есть поле с именем `category_id`. Оно может быть пустое. То есть передается в экшен значение null.

Это обработчик:

```
def update
    @post.update_attributes!(post_params)
end

private

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
    allowed = %i[title category_id content]
    params.require(:post).permit(*allowed)
end
```

Ошибку вызывает сохранение данных. Вот полный текст ошибки, из которого становится ясно, что проблема в поле `category_id`. Если его удалить из `permit`, то ошибка пропадает и данные сохраняются. Притом сохраняются значения null, передаваемые JS.

> PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "posts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_ac52d45g3n"
>   DETAIL:  Key (category_id)=(0) is not present in table "categories".

Как все же правильно отправлять форму, чтобы не было проблем со связями (`category_id`) и не было сохранения `null` в таблицу как простого текста?

Comment: ну так сохраняйте его как `null`, а не как `0`

Comment: @ArchDemon передается `null`. В `post_params` значение `null`.

Comment: Что ещё за `null`? Может, `"null"` (строка)? Это объясняет, что происходит. Попробуйте пустую строку (`""`).

Comment: @D-side а по-другому нельзя? `null` - это значение в JS, которое после отправки в экшен превращается в string. Ну это превращение даже логично. Просто может есть универсальное решение, а то не знаю даже... Вроде проблема должна быть популярной. Кстати `null` в JS попадает из того же Rails экшена (`nil`). То есть идет получение данных для формы. Форма заполняется (заполняется data в Vue.js). Далее пользователь редактирует форму и отправляет ее.

Comment: В FormData не бывает ничего, кроме строк. Проверьте, что там на самом деле.

Comment: @D-side ну там вроде все логично. Туда поступает `null`, а так как эти типы не могут передаваться от фронта к бэкенду, то идет конвертация всего в стринги. И я имел ввиду какое-то решение на стороне Rails, чтобы все преобразить как нужно... Ну знаю даже, как еще сформулировать.

Comment: Полно средств. Только все неправильные. Лучше изначально использовать другой формат для данных, поддерживающий все имеющиеся в них типы. Например, (сюрприз-сюрприз!) JSON.

Comment: @D-side то есть это отказаться от `FormData`? Я возможно сейчас задам тупой и грустный вопрос, но как передавать JSON? Я возможно и знаю, просто хочу поставить жирную и четкую точку в этом вопросе. Я просто когда читал доки, то многие использовали `FormData`, а JSON даже не встречал (вроде)...

Comment: Просто передавать в теле запроса данные в JSON, снабдив запрос правильным значением `Content-Type`. Обычный HTTP.

Comment: @D-side понял вас. А проблем особых с передачей (загрузкой) файлов быть не должно при таком формате передачи данных?

Comment: @Colibri будут. В таком случае JSON можно просто загрузить как один из файлов в том же multipart-запросе.

Comment: @D-side к слову о `FormData` - вот тут как раз его и рекомендую использовать: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/recipes.md#forms

Comment: @Colibri не вижу никаких рекомендаций. Пример вижу, но не более.

Comment: @D-side понял вас. Просто я что-то реально не могу понять, как JSON'ом передавать загружаемое изображение. Наверно, я немного не понял что вы имели ввиду в своем сообщении про `multipart`... :(

Comment: Да, скорее всего. Почитайте, что такое multipart и как он устроен.

Comment: @D-side ага. Вроде я понял (я ведь верно понял? :) ): https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/267#issuecomment-219366970

Comment: @Colibri понятия не имею, что вы поняли, но по ссылке мало что описано.

Comment: @D-side что-то не выходит. Указываю вроде бы как `multipart`, но как только дело доходит до передачи `File` из фронта, то на стороне Rails в экшене поле `cover` тупо пропадает из перечня. Если принудительно в поле `cover` в фронте помещу, например, строку `asdasd`, то она будет получена в `params` в экшене. Иначе JSON строка имеет `{}` у `cover`.